# Outlook extension with Java

Tags: java, outlook

I am trying to make an Outlook extension.
I have seen a lot of examples in .Net/C# framework with Visual Studio, but is there any other way that I can make the extension with Java?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is "how do I do this whole project" ?

Comment: Write the extension *in* .NET and use the [VSTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430.aspx) or Add-in Express libraries. If the code "must" be written in Java, use something like [IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/) (along with previous stated .NET libraries).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Java is able to produce in-proc COM servers (dlls). All Outlook addins are regular COM libraries that implement the IDTExtensibility2 interface.